# How to add the value of two pairs of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie in Javascript. I am trying to achieve to add the price of certain color and size. With this, the prices of each variant are as follows:

```
White, Small = 41
Black, Small = 51
White, Medium = 45
Black, Medium = 55
```

I would like to display the sum of it in HTML.

```js
var sizeprice = 0, colorprice = 0;    // added by Mr Jojo

function ColorWhite() {
  colorprice = 40
  sumcolorandprice = colorprice + sizeprice
  document.getElementById("current-price").innerHTML = '$' + sumcolorandprice
}

function ColorBlack() {
  colorprice = 50
  sumcolorandprice = colorprice + sizeprice
  document.getElementById("current-price").innerHTML = '$' + sumcolorandprice
}

function SizeSmall() {
  sizeprice = 1
  sumcolorandprice = colorprice + sizeprice
  document.getElementById("current-price").innerHTML = '$' + sumcolorandprice
}

function SizeMedium() {
  sizeprice = 5
  sumcolorandprice = colorprice + sizeprice
  document.getElementById("current-price").innerHTML = '$' + sumcolorandprice
}
```

```html
<span id="current-price"></span>

<button type="button" onclick="ColorWhite()">White</button>
<button type="button" onclick="ColorBlack()">Black</button>

<button type="button" onclick="SizeSmall()">Small</button>
<button type="button" onclick="SizeMedium()">Medium</button>
```

Comment: just add `var sizeprice = 0, colorprice = 0;` on your  JS script first line

Answer (score 2):

I took a stab at coding this using some better practices. I introduced an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to avoid using global variables, and used better naming practices. You want to avoid using an upper case letter as the first letter in a function name generally because people use that to denote that the function should be treated like a [Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). The logic here is to only show the price once both a color and a size are chosen. If you want price to show as soon as the first button is clicked simply take the code that is inside the `if` statement and put it outside the `if` block and then delete the `if` statement logic.

```js
/* Immediately invoked function expression wrapping all the code
   and passing in the global object, which in the case of the 
   browser is the window
*/
(function (global) {
  'use strict'; // Best practice to always use strict mode
  
  const doc = global.document;

  /* Keep track of default price constants in a single object.
     If prices changes in future it will be easy to modify
     them from one spot
  */
  const prices = {
    white: 40,
    black: 50,
    small: 1,
    medium: 5
  }

  // Use to get, set, calculate, and print prices
  const currentPrice = (() => {
    // These variables now protected in a closure and accessed
    // with the currentPrice object's methods (returned below)
    let sizePrice = 0,
        colorPrice = 0,
        totalPrice = 0;
    
    return {
      getSizePrice() {
        return sizePrice;
      },
      
      getColorPrice() {
        return colorPrice;
      },
    
      getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
      },

      setSizePrice(price) {
        sizePrice = price;
      },
    
      setColorPrice(price) {
        colorPrice = price;
      },
    
      calcTotalPrice() {
        totalPrice = sizePrice + colorPrice;
      },
    
      printTotalPrice() {
        doc.getElementById('totalPrice').textContent = `$${totalPrice}`;
      }
    }
  })();

  // Using single Event Listener for row of btns is best practice
  doc.getElementById('btnRow').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    // After listening for the click this determines which btn 
    // was clicked and adds the unique code for that btn
    switch (evt.target.id) {
      case 'btnColorWhite': 
        currentPrice.setColorPrice(prices.white);
        break;
      case 'btnColorBlack':
        currentPrice.setColorPrice(prices.black);
        break;
      case 'btnSizeSm':
        currentPrice.setSizePrice(prices.small);
        break;
      case 'btnSizeMd':
        currentPrice.setSizePrice(prices.medium);
        break;
    }
    
    // Only calculates and prints the price if both a color and 
    // size have been clicked already
    if (currentPrice.getColorPrice() !== 0 && currentPrice.getSizePrice() !== 0) {
      currentPrice.calcTotalPrice();
      currentPrice.printTotalPrice();
    }

    evt.stopPropagation();
  }, { passive: true });
})(window);
```

```css
.buttons-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-wrapper" id="btnRow">
  <button type="button" id="btnColorWhite">White</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnColorBlack">Black</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnSizeSm">Small</button>
  <button type="button" id="btnSizeMd">Medium</button>
</div>
<span id="totalPrice"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  var sumPrice = 0;

  var prices = {
    white: 40,
    black: 50,
    small: 1,
    medium: 5
  };

  function showCurrency(p) {
    return "$" + p.toFixed(2);
  }

  function setColor(c) {
    sumPrice += prices[c];
    $("#current-price").html(showCurrency(sumPrice));
  }

  function setSize(s) {
    sumPrice += prices[s];
    $("#current-price").html(showCurrency(sumPrice));
  }

  $(".color").click(function() {
    setColor($(this).val());
  });

  $(".size").click(function() {
    setSize($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="current-price"></span>

<button type="button" class="color" value="white">White</button>
<button type="button" class="color" value="black">Black</button>

<button type="button" class="size" value="small">Small</button>
<button type="button" class="size" value="medium">Medium</button>
```

This may not be the best way to capture this type of user interaction. The User can click buttons multiple times and there is no way for you to determine if they hit it once or more than once, for any of the buttons.

You can see that when the user clicks a button it adds the price to the `sumPrice`, if they click another button, the price is updated. We defined `sumPrice` as a more global variable, meaning other functions can access it. We can do this with:

```
sumPrice = sumPrice + prices['white'];
```

This same bit of code can use another operator for shorthand:

```
sumPrice += prices['white'];
```

Most of all this can also be done with JavaScript in much the same way.

```js
var sumPrice = 0;

var prices = {
  white: 40,
  black: 50,
  small: 1,
  medium: 5
};

function showCurrency(p) {
  return "$" + p.toFixed(2);
}

function setColor(c) {
  sumPrice += prices[c];
  $("#current-price").html(showCurrency(sumPrice));
}

function setSize(s) {
  sumPrice += prices[s];
  $("#current-price").html(showCurrency(sumPrice));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="current-price"></span>

<button type="button" class="color" value="white" onclick="setColor(this.value);">White</button>
<button type="button" class="color" value="black" onclick="setColor(this.value);">Black</button>

<button type="button" class="size" value="small" onclick="setSize(this.value);">Small</button>
<button type="button" class="size" value="medium" onclick="setSize(this.value);">Medium</button>
```

**Update**

If you want the User to only select one Color and one Size, you might consider using Radio Buttons instead of Buttons. See More: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Here is an example.

```js
var sumPrice = 0;

var prices = {
  white: 40,
  black: 50,
  small: 1,
  medium: 5
};

function showCurrency(p) {
  return "$" + p.toFixed(2);
}

function calcTotal(event) {
  var c = 0;
  var s = 0;
  if (document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked')) {
    c = prices[document.querySelector('input[name="color"]:checked').value];
  }
  if (document.querySelector('input[name="size"]:checked')) {
    s = prices[document.querySelector('input[name="size"]:checked').value];
  }
  document.querySelector('#current-price').innerHTML = showCurrency(c + s);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color">
  Select Color:
  <input type="radio" value="white" name="color" onclick="calcTotal()"> <label>White</label>
  <input type="radio" value="black" name="color" onclick="calcTotal()"> <label>Black</label>
</div>
<div class="size">
  Select Size:
  <input type="radio" value="small" name="size" onclick="calcTotal()"> <label>Small</label>
  <input type="radio" value="medium" name="size" onclick="calcTotal()"> <label>Medium</label>
</div>
Price: <span id="current-price">$0</span>
```

Comment: There isn't really a good reason to use jQuery in this solution (or almost anywhere in 2022). If he is a newbie to JavaScript, introducing a library that there is no good reason to learn anymore is needlessly confusing. It also doesn't logically work correctly because the total keeps adding up the more you click the buttons.

Comment: @StephenMIrving agree with both points, yet OP did not state what type of answer they were looking to receive. Hence why both versions are included. I answered the question based on the parameters defined in the question. OP did not say anything about reducing it if another option was selected.

Comment: The logic he is using in his own code would not keep adding to the total with every click and he says in description what he is trying to do is add the price of a certain color and a certain size.

Comment: Yes OPs question should have been clearer. Looks like it is their first though.

Comment: @StephenMIrving I updated my answer to give OP another example that maybe makes more sense.

Comment: It is a very thorough answer sorry to sound hyper-critical. I also provided a solution coming at the problem from a different way.

Comment: Since OP was tagged with jQuery, I don't see a problem with providing a jQuery solution.

Comment: yes i am also looking for jQuery solutions.

Comment: There is virtually no reason to ever write new code using jQuery. Modern vanilla JS can do everything the main jQuery library can do, written just as simply and running faster. It just creates totally unnecessary overhead. It is an outdated and superfluous thing to learn or continue using, and has been for more than 5 years now. If you are a beginner it is a big mistake to waste even 1min learning jQuery. [See this article from 5 years ago](https://css-tricks.com/now-ever-might-not-need-jquery/). People have been writing "you don't need jquery" articles since 2013.